# What is the reason for the T- shaped rudder trim tab on the DA42?

Tags: commercial-aviation

Why does the rudder trim tab on the DA42 have a T-shape?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it is clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "characteristic"?

Comment: I meant, aerodynamically what is the purpose of such design ?

Comment: Looks like you got your answer then. :)

Answer (score 5):

The feature was added to reduce undesirable flutter discovered during flight test.  It appears on the rudder trim tab of the DA-62 as well.

Comment: "Buzz" (a simple vibration that doesn't excite sympathetic motion in the surface and structure) or just "vibration" might be a better word than flutter.  When you get flutter you generally don't survive it.  Another purpose of those kinds of TE add-ons (and the bulged surface itself) is to help with a dead zone problem that prevented the surface from precisely centering.